# Facebook share thumbnail as part of a page

Tags: html

Alright so is it possible to share certain DIV element as a facebook thumbnail? Lets say I have some post on my website and I want to show some page content instead of a picture on facebook thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

The picture that Facebook will pick to show as a thumbnail is defined in the meta tag **og:image**. So if you want to show a specific image in a Facebook thumbnail you just add this to the header of the corresponding page:

```
<header>

   <meta property="og:image" content="path-to-your-image.jpg">

</header>
```

Comment: I dont want to show an image, I want to show something else, is that possible? Like some part of my webpage or such